# How do I preview latex math in org mode without generating image files?

Tags: org-mode, latex

So when I preview latex in emacs org, there will be a sub-folder `itximg` generated in the same folder as the .org, containing the image files.

My question is can org mode preview latex math without generating `.png`, `.svg` and alike? Those image files can be large and can clutter your folder.

For example, when atom (or many other text editors) preview markdown no extra image files are generated. Although I don't know the details of how that works behind the scenes.

Comment: I bet atom and other such editors that basically run inside a web browser use MathJax (or something similar like KaTeX).

Comment: Well, with a little peeking around markdown-preview-plus in atom it does seems they use mathjax.

Comment: Personally, I don't preview *inside* of Emacs: I export to HTML and have the file open in my browser ---this also uses MathJax in the default setup. (I use HTML because the browser refreshes faster than LaTeX compiles on my machine.)

Comment: That sounds like a good solution. Do you configure the browser to do refreshing on-save?

Comment: I haven't looked into automating the browser refresh, but I probably should.